# Send all Outline traffic over proxy to another server

Tags: networking, proxy, linux-networking, socks

i have setup an outline server on my first server lets call it outline server; and i have successfully connected to that server via outline client application.
but i need to redirect all that traffic from my outline server to another server via proxy or tunnel.
i have another server at different location which i want to accept the traffic from outline server.

below diagram shows what i want:

client ----> outline server -----> server 2 -------> destination

ps; outline server is running ubuntu and my other server is running CentOS 8

Thanks in advance

Comment: i managed to do what i want with sshuttle. but there is another probelm: i cannot forward udp ports. :(